# How can I make my Regex look for a random amount of numbers and then one word?

Tags: regex, powershell, match

I'm writing a PowerShell script that's supposed to find referenced files in another file and move them to their correct location.

I'm also writing a logfile, into which the names of the patients and the date need to be written.

I am now stuck on creating a regex line, which looks for the name and the date.
The name is split to 2 lines. I will show an example of how that looks. Besides the name, I also need the birthdate, which I will also display below.

The names and the birthdate in the file look like this (changed for obvious reasons):

```
0143101Mueller
0143101Tabea
017310316051923
```

Example result:

```
Name = Meuller Tabea
Date = 16.05.1923
```

I have tried creating a regex line, but it doesn't work yet.

This is my current regex line:

```
^([0-9]+)([a-z].*i+.)
```

At the moment, it picks up stuff that has multiple words and it doesn't seem to match the required information (name and date).
What do I need to add to the regex line so that it only looks for one word/the example I provided?

Comment: How is that a date? Also your regex is looking for one or more `i`, why?

Comment: It might be helpful if you gave an example of what you are looking for e.g. Name: Mueller Tabea; Date: ???

Comment: @Enigmativity In this example its meant like this:
0173103[16.05.1923]
Im looking for their birth date, sorry for not specifying.
isn't the `i` supposed to make it case insensitive?

Comment: @Shaneis
Name: Mueller Tabea
Date: 16.05.1923

Comment: Maybe `^(\d+)(\p{L}+)`? See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5cd%2b%29%28%5cp%7bL%7d%2b%29&i=0143101Mueller%0d%0a0143101Tabea%0d%0a017310316051923&o=m).

Comment: What's the `0173103` part then?

Comment: Can you please provide more than three lines of sample and can you also provide the expected output of your extended sample?

Answer (score 2):

Try pattern: `(\d+)([A-Za-z]+)\n\1([A-Za-z]+)\n\d+(\d{6})`

Explanation:

`\d+` = match one or more digits

`[A-Za-z]+` - match one or more letters (lowercase or uppercase)

`\1` - match text matched by first capturing group (to ensure that last name is preceded by the same number)

`\n` - match newline character

`\d{6}` - match exactly six digits

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aiUaeq/1)

Answer (score 0):

I assume this will do so:

```
^([0-9])+([A-Za-z])+
```

or:

```
^([0-9])+([A-z])+
```